# is "ServerAdmin email@domain.tld" required in the VirtualHost in Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration

I rather not have

```
 ServerAdmin
```

in my VirtualHost because all it does is attract spam.

It has no use what so ever.

Can it be ignored?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can ignore it. `ServerAdmin` directive has no default value, so if you don't specific a value, `apache` won't process it.

See more: [Directive Quick Reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/quickreference.html)